# SugarCRM 6.5 how to customize custom module view page print layout

Tags: sugarcrm

I am beginner SugarCRM developer, I have create custom module successful and working fine. detailview page click print button, printing the different layout. How can I customize this?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

SugarCRM has its own css for print media. You can check its ruls in theme style.css

Now if you want to add any further rules then you can do it following way:

```
@media print {
   …
}
```

You will need to learn more about modifying print layout using CSS. This is something using SugarCRM itself(CSS for print layout). So either you can modify existing rules  or can create new one. This [link](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) might help.